# Can I use IntelliJ Idea to assume a Git tracked file as unchanged?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'd like to use the IDE IntelliJ Idea and not the terminal to execute the command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

I hope there is a tool so that I can do a multiple selection of files to assume unchanged. Anyway I cannot find such a feature. 
Is there any way to do this from the IDE without using the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible from IDEA.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76682